# 'Windows/Super' key gets remapped to 'Alt' through TeamViewer

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, teamviewer

This seems to be an issue that only manifested in the last few versions maybe 14.04+.

<kbd>Win/Super</kbd> works as desired at the computer itself. Through TeamViewer however <kbd>Win/Super</kbd> is instead mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

I do have `Send Key Combinations` checked in TeamViewer and any other combinations seems to work as intended <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my particular case was a result of an Autohotkey script that was running. Gone now.

Comment: For anyone else, I had Autohotkey enabled but disabling it didn't solve this for me.

Comment: Perhaps you have some other service/tool running that is intercepting the keystrokes.